# Storing line by line from text file into char array using char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, system

Hello  I writing a program to execute commands from the text file. The code below is used to store line by line into char array first.

So I expect it to do something like

```
args[0]= The first line of text file  
args[1]= The second line of text file
... and so on
```

In my code, all of the arrays would be covered by the last array. And I can't figure out why.

Can anyone help me fix this and tell me why my code does that. Also I need to keep char *args[]. cos I would use it with execvp() later.

```
int main(int argc, const char * av[]) {    
    FILE *fp;    
    fp = fopen(av[1],"r");

    int n_lines=0;        
    char in[100],*args[16];        
    int size=sizeof(in);

     while(fgets(in, size, fp)!=NULL){        
        args[n_lines] = in;                
        printf("Args[0] is %s\n",args[0]);            
        n_lines++;
    }

     printf("Now Args[0] is %s\n",args[0]);
}
```

Output

```
zacks-MacBook-Pro:prac2 zack$ ./a.out test    
Args[0] is ./addone    
Args[0] is ./add    
Now Args[0] is ./add
```

Comment: Independetly of you problem: you know that you'll run into problems if your file has more then 16 lines.

Comment: Independently of your problem, you should check if file is there and close the file pointer upon content being read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n_lines=0;        
char in[100],*args[16];        
int size=sizeof(in);

while(fgets(in, size, fp)!=NULL){        
    args[n_lines] = in;                
    printf("Args[0] is %s\n",args[0]);            
    n_lines++;
}
```

The value of `in` is overwritten on each iteration, you need to reserve space (using `malloc->strcpy` or `strdup` if available):

```
char in[100], *args[16];

while (fgets(in, sizeof in, fp) != NULL) {
    args[n_lines] = strdup(in);
    ...
    n_lines++;
}
```

Or use a 2D array (an adjust of `sizeof` is required in `fgets`):

```
char in[16][100];

while (fgets(in[n_lines], sizeof in[0], fp) != NULL) {
    ...
    n_lines++;
}
```

And as pointed out by @MichaelWalz in comments: you'll run into problems if your file has more then 16 lines.

Change to

```
while (fgets(in[n_lines], sizeof in[0], fp) != NULL) {
    ...
    if (++n_lines == (sizeof in / sizeof in[0])) break;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz, thanks for the edit, my english is very poor :)